# EAV querying and tables

Tags: mysql, database, entity-attribute-value, querying

Now I have 4 tables:

```
table categories:
-id
-category

table products:
-id
-product
-price
-image

table attributes:
-id
-attribute
-product_id

table values:
-product_id
-attribute_id
-value
```

And I'm querying with:

```
SELECT `id`, `product`, `price`, `image` FROM `products` WHERE `category_id` = $category->id
```

Now I got array of products for this category and need to get it's properties:
next query:

```
SELECT `products`.`id` AS `product_id`, 
`attributes`.`attribute`, 
`values`.`value` 
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `attributes` ON (`attributes`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `values` ON (`values`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
AND `values`.`attribute_id` = `attributes`.`id`) 
WHERE `products`.`id` IN ($ids)
```

And it's get the attributes with values but I'm wondering about one thing:
If it's possible to get rid of `'product_id'` column in `table attributes` and get attributes and values without that column? Now it's a whole bunch of duplicating attributes for example:

```
table attributes 
-id 1
-attribute Weight
-product_id 1

-id 2
-attribute Weight
-product_id 2
```

While I want just:

```
-id 1
-attribute Weight
```

sorry for my english, if some part of my post needs more explanation please let me now

Comment: You are missing the `category_id` from the description of your `product` table.

Comment: Putting aside EAV's limitations, your design suggests that different products can have different allowed attributes (those stored in table `attribute`). If you don't want such functionality, you could use @vucetica's approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you want your attributes to be product specific, but you obviously, don't. Also, you don't need product_id in your values table, if you have it in your attributes table. So your tables make more sense if they are like:

```
table categories:
-id
-category

table products:
-id
-product
-price
-image
-category_id

table attributes:
-id
-attribute
-product_id

table values:
-attribute_id
-value
```

Actually, I would make it a lot more simple EAV:

```
table categories:
-id
-category

table products:
-id
-product
-price
-image
-category_id

table attributes:
-id
-product_id
-attribute
-value
```

And then, your query would look like:

```
SELECT id, product, price, image, attribute, value
FROM products
    INNER JOIN attributes ON products.id = attributes.product_id
WHERE products.category_id = :category_id
```

Make sure you have appropriate indexes. Also, the way you wanted to do it with selecting product ids and then putting them into IN, is a bad practice.

Comment: but if i have for intance 10 attributes?

Comment: it will return 10 rows. don't you want that?

Comment: That will limit the OP to one category per product.  That's an observation, not a criticism.

Comment: Yes, that's one more thing that can be improved in the original design, too.